# Connect PHP in Linux to db2 in iSeries

Tags: php, db2, db2-400

I have a PHP application running in a Docker container on Linux RedHat for Power. This application connects to a DB2 for LUW instance.

To connect to DB2 from PHP I am currently using pdo_ibm driver which I installed as follows in the container:

```
RUN curl https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/linuxx64_odbc_cli.tar.gz | tar -xz -C /clidriver
RUN curl https://pecl.php.net/get/PDO_IBM-1.5.0.tgz | tar -xz -C /pdo
RUN cp -r /clidriver/clidriver/include /pdo/PDO_IBM-1.5.0/include
RUN cd /pdo/PDO_IBM-1.5.0 && phpize && ./configure --with-pdo-ibm=/clidriver/clidriver && make install && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_ibm
```

Basically, first the driver is downloaded, then the pdo_ibm connector is also downloaded, after this, some headers file from the driver are copied to pdo_ibm folder and finally the pdo_connector is built and enable.

The DB2 for LUW instance will be decommissioned and I will only have a DB2 instance running on iSeries. Does anyone have any experience on how to accomplish this? Will the difference be only to change the driver? Or is it needed some extra configuration?

I was able to connect to DB2 on iSeries using unixODBC downloading IBM i Access. However, I need to do it on PDO since the code of the app cannot be changed at all.

Comment: the IBM clidriver can be used to connect to i-series __provided__ that you purchase and deploy a license  file (for db2-connect personal)  in the license subdirectory of the clidriver in your container  ( __or__ connect indirectly via a Db2-connect gateway, __or__  server-based licensing is activated meaning no client-side licenses need to be deployed).

Comment: Yes, this can only be done with the $pend money command.